# Eclipse - Common Preference settings file(.epf) for Linux and Windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

1. In Windows Eclipse, I exported preferences as sample.epf.
2. I opened sample.epf file.
3. I found **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15"** in sample.epf.
4. It using direct paths, so I can not use it in Linux.

Do you know any common format will work in both Linux and Windows, or is there any possibility to use **Environment Variables** like JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

No, because JAVA_HOME could point to, well, *anything*--1.3, 1.7, who knows?  You want complete and conscious control over what's in a project's Java Build Path and complete isolation from the OS if you want your projects to be portable.  It's ok to have the preferences refer to things unique to the machine, you can change those on other machines, it's the settings in the *projects* that you don't want tied a specific machine.  Start by setting their Java Build Path to use an Execution Environment to find its JRE.